# Set default port number in HTML help

Tags: r

Well, the title is quite self-explanatory... Is it possible to set default port number for R's HTML help? Each time I start HTML help, port number gets changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `help(startDynamicHelp)`:

> Details:
>
> ```
>  This function starts the internal HTTP server, which runs on the
>  loopback interface (‘127.0.0.1’).  If ‘options("help.ports")’ is
>  set to a vector of integer values, ‘startDynamicHelp’ will try
>  those ports in order; otherwise, it tries up to 10 random ports to
>  find one not in use.  It can be disabled by setting the
>  environment variable ‘R_DISABLE_HTTPD’ to a non-empty value.
> ```

So it looks like you can try to override it via `options("help.ports")`, appropriately set.  The randomization appears to be a feature.

Comment: Sublime answer! Thanks a lot!